# iFrame and Javascript to parent document

Tags: javascript, iframe, external, parent

I have an iFrame with an external website. I know about the same domain rule, so I am trying to invoke some javascript via the `src` to the parent. Currently I have:

```
<iframe id="my_frame" src="http://other.com"></iframe>
```

and I change the `src` using javascript as follows:

```
<iframe id="my_frame" src="javascript:document.write("blah");"></iframe>
```

but using the `parent` does not work:

```
<iframe id="my_frame" src="javascript:parent.document.write("blah");"></iframe>
```

Does the same domain rule also apply for the parent or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm confused. How is `src="javascript:parent.document.write("blah");"` going to work?

Comment: I think that is part of his question. :)

Comment: sorry, "blah" in the above is supposed to be single quoted. I hand-wrote it here. But in my editor it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is either a workaround gone awry, or it's genius and I don't recognize it :) What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to write into the sub-frame, or from the sub-frame into the parent document?

Comment: I actually thought it is something new, and tried the codes. Well, guess it is not genius. :P

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your intention is to write something to the document containing the iframe.

now, first off, your first snippet can't work because the double-quoted string inside the javascript is itself inside an attribute value, which is also enclosed in double quotes. It should read:

```
<iframe id="my_frame" src="javascript:document.write('blah');"></iframe>
```

This is probably also wrong in your last snippet, so fix accordingly.

Still, I don't really see what you are trying to achieve. Care to explain why you are trying to use this?